# What kind of job three friends do in Pyaar Ka Punchnama?

Tags: character, pyar-ka-panchnama

Rajat, Nishant and Vikrant are the friends whose love-life is shown in the Pyaar Ka Punchnama movie. We have seen them doing work and in their office also. But I got no clue to find any instance of what kind of job they do.

So anybody has any idea about what is the job that they do in the movie?

Comment: @Tyler, I think the tags should be "analysis" and "Pyaar-ka-punchnama", because the question is more on "analysis", rather than on "plot explanation".

Comment: Considering you're asking about their job, analysis doesn't fit as it is more a question of their profession.  Obviously not seeing the movie I'm unsure how important their jobs are to the plot so please correct me if I'm wrong.  As far as the `bollywood` tag, that is becoming a meta tag for this as this question is not about Bollywood, but a movie made in Bollywood, therefore the tag does not apply.

Comment: @TylerShads, Actually this question dissects the movie to deep, their job is not too much important for understanding the plot. So what should be an ideal tag to make my intention around this question clear? I am trying to like detect what might their job be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rajat (Kartik Tiwari), Nishant "Liquid" Agarwal (Divyendu Sharma) and Vikrant Chaudhary (Rayo Bakhirta) are bachelors who live together in a flat in Noida. Film not more focused on what jobs they were doing. It is more focused on how girls use boys. Though some circumstances show their work.

- Nishant - Works in IT field.
- Rajat - Doing some job.
- Vikrant - Works in musical field.

Nishant is used to show some work with coding and computers stuff so behaves like working IT. Vikrant is shown as playing Guitar many times so guessed about musical field (may be shown hobby and doing job in some office). And Rajat is shown as doing some office work ay be in marketing and his girlfriend wanted to be him in her control. Film not focused more on jobs. Only shown as how girls use boys in every field. Like Charu use Nishant to do her office work.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyaar_Ka_Punchnama

Comment: How can you conclude their jobs?

Comment: @Mistu4u :Updated answer.

Comment: I think you can delete the story part in your answer. Let us make it to the point. Anyways thanks for the edited addition.

Comment: Correction - Vikrant works in IT. You can somewhat see the Visual Studio IDE in the sequence where Rajat repeatedly calls him up before his first date.

Answer (score 2):

All the three (Nishant,Vikram and Rajat) are working in IT industry. There are various proofs of it.

1. They all are seen coding in various scenes. Vikrant is seen coding
   in NetBeans of something like that tool. Also Nishant and Rajat are
   seen in there offices and doing coding.
2. They all are having holidays on Saturday and Sunday, which is
   generally the culture in IT industries.
3. They all are seen discussing their salaries which is around 35,000 to
   40,000 Rs which is also general salaries offered in IT.

Also Vikrant's playing Guitar is totally irrelevant to his job as its just his hobby to release stress.